# Need some clarification of a Queue and a LinkedList implementation

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
/*
private Queue<Card> cards = new LinkedList<Card>();

*/
```

I am using a Queue and a LinkedList to process a deck of Black Jack playing cards.

Now, my understanding is that the queue holds the cards, and the `LinkedList` grants access to the `Queue`, correct?

If not, can someone give me a break-down of what the above code does?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a linked list *and* a queue. The class [`LinkedList<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implements the interface [`Queue<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). You are creating a linked list, but then using it as a queue.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much.  So this means I can use the methods associated with a Queue such as "add" and "remove" correct?

Comment: @edxyz: Yes, you can use the methods available on `Queue`. It's also possible to access the methods on `LinkedList` by casting but you should avoid doing this as it defeats the point of declaring the variable as `Queue<Card>`.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, my understanding is that the queue holds the cards, and the linkedlist grants access to the queue, correct?

No. `Queue` is an interface (an abstraction, a way to define contract) while `LinkedList` is an implementation of that interface. In other words it works hard to fulfill that contract.

In this particular case [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) is a very restrictive interface that exposes only few possible operations of a `LinkedList`.

Real life example: bank is an institution with employees, treasury and offices. Internet is a way you access the bank, providing some *interface* and capabilities. When using a mobile application or speaking with a bank consultant via phone you are still using the same bank, but with a different interface.

Answer (score 0):

`Queue` is interface that gives you possibility to interact with underlying object of `LinkedList` as with queue. So you cannot call method to get object by `index` and so on. So `Queue` cuts functionality of `LinkedList` that you don't require when want to use queue mechanism.